# How to insert/update a partitioned table in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

**Problem statement:**
I need to insert/update a few columns in a big query table that is partitioned by date.So basically I need to do the necessary changes for each partitioned date (done by day).
(its the sessions table that is created automatically by linking the GA View to BQ so I haven't done the partition manually but its automatically taken care by google).

query reference from [google_docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/using-dml-with-partitioned-tables)

my query:

[image: MY QUERY AND ERROR]

I also tried the below :

[image]

Can anyone help me here ? sorry I am a bit naive with BQ.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to insert into a wildcard table, a meta-table that is actually composed of multiple tables. Wildcard table is read only and cannot be inserted into.

Comment: Hey @Hua Zhang : Thanks for the comment. I didn't know this.Is it possible to overwrite the  wildcard tables ?  Scenario - Data is copied from the session_* daily table to a smaller say small_subset_* table and the data has gone garbage for a month - so I need to replace that 1 month of data in the small_subset_*  ?

Answer (score 1):

As Hua said, `ga_sessions_*` is not a partitioned table, but represents many tables, each with a different suffix.

You probably want to do this then:

```
INSERT INTO `p.d.ga_sessions_20191125` (visitNumber, visitId)
SELECT 1, 1574
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I didn't know this.Is it possible to overwrite the wildcard tables ? Scenario - Data is copied from the session_* daily table to a smaller say small_subset_* table and the data has gone garbage for a month - so I need to replace that 1 month of data in the small_subset_* ? –

Comment: It seems you want to ask a new stack overflow question?